# Como trabalhar com menu dropdown multi-level no bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando bootstrap e gostaria de saber como eu faço para trabalhar com menu dropdown com multi-level?

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-warning">Item1</a>
<a href="paroquias.php" class="btn btn-warning">Item2</a>
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Menu-Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn btn-warning" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Menu</a></li>   
        <li class="divider"></li>  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            SubMenu1
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>           
            <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubMenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O `bootstrap` não suporta mais dropdown multi level nativamente, porém você pode usar um exemplo como [Este aqui](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) para fazer o que você deseja.

Comment: Achei legal, mas por algum motivo, não está funcionando.
Dei um Ctrl +C e Ctrl V e nada.
Obrigado.

Comment: Você copiou o HTML e o CSS ou só o HTML?

Comment: Os dois.
E coloquei em arquivos separados.
Deve ser algum jquery que deve estar faltando.

Comment: O que vc me recomenda, @Richard?